# Time/Space complexity of PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, complexity-theory

Is there a way or a resource for finding the time and space complexity of the Array implementation in PHP other than calculating it by hand?

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible. - [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

From what I can tell it would seem that it has the general complexity of a map

Comment: In the average case is O(1) but the worst case is O(n) with malicious handling: http://murilo.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/deeper-look-at-phps-array-worst-case/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because it acts like a hash table, you will have `O(1)` time when accessing an element by a key.

If you are looping through the array, naturally you will have `O(n)` time.

If you have time, you can actually check out PHP's [implementation of array here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c)

Answer (score 5):

Accessing and iterating is describe by @Mike-Lewis so far

- Setting a value: O(1)
- Append: O(1) (Its the same as setting a value to the key "length")
- Prepend: O(n) (Its a guess, but should fit, because it should rewrite the existing keys)
- Unset: O(1)

Anything missed?

Comment: - Insert: O(n) (It's guess, because the existing values which come after the new one have to be rewritten)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Mike Lewis said, I would add, that one array element in PHP occupies minimum of 52 bytes ([proof](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41053&edit=3))

Comment: Just for the record, as of 2020 for PHP 7.3 this amount is about 2.5 times less. [More about this.](https://nikic.github.io/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html)

Comment: Anyone knows the memory performance of SplFixedArray compared to `array`?

Comment: How about php8, has this reduced in memory usage?