# Is there Java HashMap equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, hashmap

I need PHP object similar to HashMap in Java, but I didn't find when I googled, so if someone knows how I can mimic HashMaps in PHP, help would be appreciated.

Comment: What characterizes a hash map for you?

Comment: I need key/value pairs, and I need to get keys as array form the map.

Comment: `$keys = array_keys($array);` (and also see sushils answer below)

Comment: Arrays are actually the only data structure in PHP (if you don't consider classes/objects as data structure). It provides a key/value structure and you can get the keys easily with `array_keys`. You could write a wrapper class if you want to.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Arrays in PHP can have Key Value structure.

Comment: @Gabi: If it walks like a duck, swims like a duck and quacks like a duck... PHP manual says: *An array in PHP is actually an ordered map.*

Comment: @Felix Kling AFAIK PHP arrays don't have O(1) lookup/insertion/deletion, so they don't quack like hashmaps

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru Related: [Time/Space complexity of PHP Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641052/time-space-complexity-of-php-array).

Comment: @Gabi: The internal implementation of arrays in PHP _are_ hash maps.

Comment: @Gabi: This looks interesting in this regard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904049/php-array-performance

Comment: @Gabi: Well, you are not totally wrong ;) As the accepted answer says (and the code seems to confirm) *linked lists* are used as collision strategy. So yes, lookup and deletion might not be `O(1)` but I think the overhead is negligible in most cases.

Comment: @Michael: Well then it's a perfect replacement :) Thanks, I didn't know (I don't have that much to do with Java).

Comment: This is still not a HashMap, because I can't use objects as keys :(.

Comment: @knub you're saying it's not a Generic HashMap -- indeed -- but it is a with the type HashMap<scalar, mixed>.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt collision strategy is one thing but linked lists also preserve insertion order making our HashMap<scalar, mixed> an OrderedHashMap<scalar, mixed>.

Comment: Yes, but it only works for strings and ints (no objects)

Comment: @GabiPurcaru Only a hashmap that does not handle collisions can be O(1) for lookup,insert and delete. But you are correct in that php array lookup is not O(1), but actually O(n) worst case, as PHP uses chaining from what I understand...

Comment: @MMauro you can just hash the objects yourself and use those String outputs as array keys?

Answer (score 46):

### Create a Java like HashMap in PHP with O(1) read complexity.

Open a phpsh terminal:

```
php> $myhashmap = array();
php> $myhashmap['mykey1'] = 'myvalue1';
php> $myhashmap['mykey2'] = 'myvalue2';
php> echo $myhashmap['mykey2'];
myvalue2
```

The complexity of the `$myhashmap['mykey2']` in this case appears to be constant time O(1), meaning that as the size of $myhasmap approaches infinity, the amount of time it takes to retrieve a value given a key stays the same.

**Evidence the php array read is constant time:**

Run this through the PHP interpreter:

```
php> for($x = 0; $x < 1000000000; $x++){
 ... $myhashmap[$x] = $x . " derp";
 ... }
```

The loop adds 1 billion key/values, it takes about 2 minutes to add them all to the hashmap which may exhaust your memory.

Then see how long it takes to do a lookup:

```
php> system('date +%N');echo "  " . $myhashmap[10333] . "  ";system('date +%N');
786946389  10333 derp  789008364
```

**So how fast is the PHP array map lookup?**

The `10333` is the key we looked up.  1 million nanoseconds == 1 millisecond.  The amount of time it takes to get a value from a key is 2.06 million nanoseconds or about 2 milliseconds.  About the same amount of time if the array were empty.  This looks like constant time to me.

Comment: Not constant time... Assuming that the underlying implementation is an array-based hashmap, then due to the need to handle collisions, the best you could do is O(log n) in the case where collisions are stored as self-balanced-trees (such as the Java implementation of hashmap), but might even be stored in a linked-list (chaining), which gives a worst-case of O(n).  This is true for both insertion and lookup, but average case will be close to O(1)...

Comment: For data set size that consume the whole memory of one computer (say 8 GB), lookup time is a handful of milliseconds.  So it's "so close to constant time it's basically constant time", but if you want to be mathematically correct carrying things out to 10 billion boxes carried out to infinity, it's O(n log n).  I can nitpick too. :)  I use constant time here means "This won't be your bottleneck bro, don't even trip dog".

Comment: I agree, it probably will not be a bottleneck, as O(log n) for all operations are still very fast. Point is just that the only way to get constant time hashing is if the hashfunction is perfect, and no colission can exist. If not perfect, the best you get is O(log n). However, according to: http://phpinternalsbook.com/hashtables/basic_structure.html php uses chaining, which has a worst-case of O(N). I don't know is that is the case, as I would expect a solution achieving log n to be used, such as self-balanced-tree, but if that is the case, the distinction between O(N) and O(1) is not trivial.

Answer (score 43):

Depending on what you want you might be interested in the SPL Object Storage class.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

It lets you use objects as keys, has an interface to count, get the hash and other goodies.

```
$s = new SplObjectStorage;
$o1 = new stdClass;
$o2 = new stdClass;
$o2->foo = 'bar';

$s[$o1] = 'baz';
$s[$o2] = 'bingo';

echo $s[$o1]; // 'baz'
echo $s[$o2]; // 'bingo'
```

Comment: THIS. boztek you are underrated

Comment: SplObjectStorage has some downsides: When you use foreach, the keys are integers. And you can't retrieve a list of keys and values from it. In my case i decided to use a custom class implementing ArrayAccess, Iterator and Countable.

Comment: @carlosvini actually you can http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php#114059

Comment: best answer here

Answer (score 20):

```
$fruits = array (
    "fruits"  => array("a" => "Orange", "b" => "Banana", "c" => "Apple"),
    "numbers" => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    "holes"   => array("first", 5 => "second", "third")
);

echo $fruits["fruits"]["b"]
```

outputs 'Banana'

taken from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Comment: What if I want to declare an *empty array* and do the assigns like:

`"fruits"  => array("a" => "Orange", "b" => "Banana", "c" => "Apple")` after?

Comment: @Diego `$fruits = array(); $fruits['fruits'] = array('a' => 'Orange',...);` ...actually, you could even just do this right off the bat: `$fruits['fruits']['a'] = 'Orange'; $fruits['holes']['first'] = 5; $fruits['numbers'][] = 1;` you don't even need to necessarily create any of the arrays with `array()`.

Answer (score 10):

### HashMap that also works with keys other than strings and integers with O(1) read complexity (depending on quality of your own hash-function).

You can make a simple hashMap yourself. What a hashMap does is storing items in a array using the hash as index/key. Hash-functions give collisions once in a while (not often, but they may do), so you have to store multiple items for an entry in the hashMap. That simple is a hashMap:

```
class IEqualityComparer {
    public function equals($x, $y) {
        throw new Exception("Not implemented!");
    }
    public function getHashCode($obj) {
        throw new Exception("Not implemented!");
    }
}

class HashMap {
    private $map = array();
    private $comparer;

    public function __construct(IEqualityComparer $keyComparer) {
        $this->comparer = $keyComparer;
    }

    public function has($key) {
        $hash = $this->comparer->getHashCode($key);

        if (!isset($this->map[$hash])) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($this->map[$hash] as $item) {
            if ($this->comparer->equals($item['key'], $key)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        $hash = $this->comparer->getHashCode($key);

        if (!isset($this->map[$hash])) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($this->map[$hash] as $item) {
            if ($this->comparer->equals($item['key'], $key)) {
                return $item['value'];
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function del($key) {
        $hash = $this->comparer->getHashCode($key);

        if (!isset($this->map[$hash])) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($this->map[$hash] as $index => $item) {
            if ($this->comparer->equals($item['key'], $key)) {
                unset($this->map[$hash][$index]);
                if (count($this->map[$hash]) == 0)
                    unset($this->map[$hash]);

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function put($key, $value) {
        $hash = $this->comparer->getHashCode($key);

        if (!isset($this->map[$hash])) {
            $this->map[$hash] = array();
        }

        $newItem = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);        

        foreach ($this->map[$hash] as $index => $item) {
            if ($this->comparer->equals($item['key'], $key)) {
                $this->map[$hash][$index] = $newItem;
                return;
            }
        }

        $this->map[$hash][] = $newItem;
    }
}
```

For it to function you also need a hash-function for your key and a comparer for equality (if you only have a few items or for another reason don't need speed you can let the hash-function return 0; all items will be put in same bucket and you will get O(N) complexity)

Here is an example:

```
class IntArrayComparer extends IEqualityComparer {
    public function equals($x, $y) {
        if (count($x) !== count($y))
            return false;

        foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($y[$key]) || $y[$key] !== $value)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getHashCode($obj) {
        $hash = 0;
        foreach ($obj as $key => $value)
            $hash ^= $key ^ $value;

        return $hash;
    }
}

$hashmap = new HashMap(new IntArrayComparer());

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
        $hashmap->put(array($i, $j), $i * 10 + $j);
    }
}

echo $hashmap->get(array(3, 7)) . "<br/>";
echo $hashmap->get(array(5, 1)) . "<br/>";

echo ($hashmap->has(array(8, 4))? 'true': 'false') . "<br/>";
echo ($hashmap->has(array(-1, 9))? 'true': 'false') . "<br/>";
echo ($hashmap->has(array(6))? 'true': 'false') . "<br/>";
echo ($hashmap->has(array(1, 2, 3))? 'true': 'false') . "<br/>";

$hashmap->del(array(8, 4));
echo ($hashmap->has(array(8, 4))? 'true': 'false') . "<br/>";
```

Which gives as output:

```
37
51
true
false
false
false
false
```

Comment: `IEqualityComparer` should be an `interface` here

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom HashMap class for that in php.
example as shown below containing the basic HashMap attributes such as get and set.

```
class HashMap{

        public $arr;

        function init() {

            function populate() {
                return null;
            }
            
            // change to 999 for efficiency
            $this->arr = array_map('populate', range(0, 9));

            return $this->arr;

        }
        
        function get_hash($key) {
            $hash = 0;

            for ($i=0; $i < strlen($key) ; $i++) { 
                $hash += ord($key[$i]);
            }
            
            // arr index starts from 0
            $hash_idx = $hash % (count($this->arr) - 1); 
            return $hash_idx;
            
        }

        function add($key, $value) {
            $idx = $this->get_hash($key);
            
            if ($this->arr[$idx] == null) {
                $this->arr[$idx] = [$value];
            } else{

                $found = false;

                $content = $this->arr[$idx];
                
                $content_idx = 0;
                foreach ($content as $item) {

                    // checking if they have same number of streams
                    if ($item == $value) {

                        $content[$content_idx] = [$value];
                        $found = true;
                        break;

                    }
                    
                    $content_idx++;
                }

                if (!$found) {
                    // $value is already an array
                    array_push($content, $value);

                    // updating the array
                    $this->arr[$idx] = $content;
                }

            }

            return $this->arr;

        }

        function get($key) {

            $idx = $this->get_hash($key);
            $content = $this->arr[$idx];

            foreach ($content as $item) {
                if ($item[1] == $key) {
                    return $item;
                    break;
                }
            }
                
        }

    }
```

Hope this was useful