# extract distinct tag value from xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

i have a xml file of contact as follows

**contacts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contacts>
  <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
    <Name>yName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547012</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547011</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547012</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
 </contacts>
```

here you can see that tag `contact_no` has some duplicate. i want to remove duplicate and store only distinct contact no save the xml file using php

the xml will be as follows with three distinct contact nos after applying process.

**contact.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <contacts>
      <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
        <Name>xName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
      </contact>

       <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547012</contact_no>
        <Name>xName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>

      </contact>
       <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547011</contact_no>
        <Name>xName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
      </contact>

     <contacts>
```

i have searches in DOMDocument ad simpleXMLElement but couldn't find success.
is there any function or method to implement this. thanks in advance.

Comment: if anyone has no suggestion. stop to downvote.

Comment: Your `contacts.xml` has wrong syntax. Example : `<Email>` must be end with `</Email>` not `</msg>`.

Comment: Please provide valid `xml`.

Comment: it by mistake i update it.

Answer (score 0):

using `simplexml`and `xpath`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

// create array with all non-unique <contact_no>
$ids = $xml->xpath("/contacts/contact/contact_no");
$ids = array_diff(array_count_values(array_map("strval", $ids)), array("1"));

// select each non-unique entry and delete it
foreach ($ids as $id => $count) {   
    $results = $xml->xpath("/contacts/contact[contact_no = '$id']");
    for ($i = $count; $i > 0; $i--) unset($results[$i][0]); 
}
```

see it working: https://eval.in/84939

**Comments**
`line 04:` select all `<contact_no>` and put it into `array $ids`
`line 05:` these are objects, so we...
     1. use `array_map()` to convert them to `string`
     2. use `array_count_values()` to have the `contact_no` as `key` and its count as `value`
     3. use `array_diff()` to remove all unique elements (`value = 1`)
`line 09:` select all `<contact>` with its `no` stored in `$id` into `$results`
`line 10:` loop through `$results` and `unset()` all `<contact>` but one

Answer (score -1):

I have developed this code through the DomDocument.
This my xml file which i have named contact.xml. Please have a look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
        <Name>xName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
        <Name>yName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547012</contact_no>
        <Name>xName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547011</contact_no>
        <Name>xName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547012</contact_no>
        <Name>xName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
        <Name>xName</Name>
        <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
    </contact>
    </contacts>
```

Now I have developed the functionality for it like this:

```
<?php
        $dom=new DOMDocument();
        $dom->load("contact.xml");
        $tt=$dom->getElementsByTagName("contact_no");
        foreach ($tt as $tt1){
            $dt= new DOMXPath($dom);
            $dtlist=$dt->query('/contacts/contact/contact_no[text()="'.$tt1->nodeValue.'"]');
            $count=0;
            foreach($dtlist as $tmt){
                if($count!=0){
                    $tmt->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($tmt->parentNode);
                }
                $count++;
            }
        }
        $dom->saveXML();
        $dom->save("contact.xml");
        ?>
```

Hope you will enjoy the code. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score -2):

We can resolve this by using the SimpleXMl function of PHP for xml operations and using the loop where we can remove the parent element when the contact_no got matched.

```
    <?php

        $str = <<<_END
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <contacts>
  <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
    <Name>yName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547012</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547011</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547012</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
   <contact>
    <contact_no>9782547000</contact_no>
    <Name>xName</Name>
    <Email>xEmail@gmail.com</Email>
  </contact>
 <contacts>
        _END;
    $xml=simplexml_load_string($str);

    $seen=array();

    $len=$xml->contact->count();
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
        $key=(string) $xml->contact[$i]->contact_no;
        if (isset($seen[$key])) {
            unset($xml->contact[$i]);
            $len--;
            $i--;
        }else{
            $seen[$key]=1;
        }
    }

    echo $xml->asXML();
    ?>
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: thanks but i don't want to use array or traverse all tags of file because file may have lacs of records.

Comment: why no arrays? btw. @Avi least post the link where u got this code from since this is not your own. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922039/php-remove-duplicate-xml-feed-entries

Comment: @dan if i use array it takes a lot of memory and processing time if my xml file has a large no of records(in lacs)

Comment: @Satish Sharma  posting another answer under it to your question without the arrays. Please have a look and update me if you have any queries.

Comment: Always available for solutions of Problem :)