# Which languages support multi-key associative arrays?

Tags: arrays

Which languages support non-scalar associative array keys?

I want to make an array like:

[key1,key2,key3,key4]=>[object]

I guess I'd be satisfied if the multiple keys had to each be scalars, although bonus points if they can be any data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called hash tables (or hashmaps). You can implement them in most languages. Some languages already have support for hash tables like c++, java, lisp, python ...

Here are some references for some languages:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html in java
- http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_maphas.htm in lisp
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/ in c++

Also, from personal experience I found out that they are extreamly easy to work in lisp.

Comment: Ah and in fact PHP has it, SplObjectStorage class. Woot. http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that SplObjectStorage would work either, that's another question though.

Comment: In php you can index arrays using strings (don't know if this works for you). Here's a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841379/is-there-java-hashmap-equivalent-in-php

Comment: Yes but what I want to do is index arrays using arrays, so that any of the members of the array can be used to navigate the index. So like if an array contains ['foo',400] and that node points to the next node that contains 'bar' then array[400] will give 'bar' and so will array['foo'].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any that support them directly.  Perl does allow multiple scalar keys in its associative arrays via `$var{$key1, $key2}` but all that does is automatically concatenate the two values into a larger one and is equivalent to `$var{"$key1$;$key2"}`. `$;` is "\034" so there will be unexpected collisions if your key strings contain that value.

The same trick could be applied in any language by serializing the more complex data type into a single string.