# Compare array values from one array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

**NOTE:**

I'm new to php and mysql.

**Background info:**

I have +/- 30,000 products and they are from 7 different supplier and they have a lot of the same products

let's say i have 1 product and three of the suppliers have the it, i need to publish the product with the lowest price and the other two product stay unpublished

that is the basic idea and this must run through the 30,000 products and check and see if there are any matches and run the publishing function

**SQL setup:**

There are two tables **xxxx_virtuemart_product** and **xxxx_virtuemart_product_prices**

There are three rows in xxxx_virtuemart_product ▬▬▬ product_id,product_sku,published ▬▬▬

There are two rows in xxxx_virtuemart_product_prices ▬▬▬ product_id,product_price ▬▬▬

**My little bit of code:**

I have this little code because i'm stuck, how can i make a check to see if there are any matches and then run a query to change the published value of the product with the lowest price?

i know there is a way to use the query to check for matches, but do not understand how to do is

```
$query = "SELECT `product_sku` FROM `xxxx_virtuemart_product`";
$query_run = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    foreach ($row as $key => $ps){

    }
}
```

The below code is to check the price (not query optimize just a rough draft)

```
$z = //products price;
$x = //products price;
$c = //products price;

if ($z >= $x && $c >= $x) {

    //the this products published value to 1

}else if ($x >= $z && $c >= $z) {

    //the this products published value to 1

}else if ($z >= $c && $x >= $c) {

    //the this products published value to 1

}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks for reading

any questions are welcome.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Hi h2ooooooo, i know that there will be a learning curve to PDO but it looks like it will be better in the long run, what is your choice?

Comment: Personally I prefer PDO. The learning curve is not as bad as you might think, and you can make a class fairly easy that handles regular queries for you. In our DB library at work we simply have to use `$db->FetchRows("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id = :id", array(":id" => 123))` to get our results.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not about to compare arrays but more algorithm.
I will try this way.
1)SQL query to retrieve all the products : sql_products
2)construct a hashmap those key is product SKU (see : [PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641052/time-space-complexity-of-php-array))

To construct PHP hashmap : use arrays of arrays.
Example :
product_map[] = array();

foreach sql_product of sql_products :
 - product_map[sql_product[SKU]][] = array(sql_product[supplier], sql_product[price], sql_product[information])
end of loop

Then loop again over the map of products constructed and sort each product record by price : that means you have to write a function to sort array (supplier, price, information).

Now you have a map of product : SKU => array(of array (supplier, price, information))

Comment: Thanks Yoong kim, will look in to it.

Comment: Instead adding and sort array, you can check if product with SKU is added to array and compare price with current. If is lower then add id to separate array to unpublish them later. If is greater then replece added with current and so on.

Comment: Yoong Kim, do you mean like this - array structure - product_sku => supplier => then the three suppliers prices that i run a foreach and if statment to see the lowest price and run a query to change the publish value?